# Image Matching and Recognition in R (document signatures)

Tags: python, r, image-processing

I came across some answers regarding the possibility of image recognition (and further matching) in Python and other languages, as well as papers describing a machine learning process for matching signatures*, but none in R regarding the possibility of recognizing signatures. In Python, a language in which I might try a hand at, I found the [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) library for face recognition. But still is not exactly what I need.

For an R user (and someone willing to instruct himself in Python), what is the best strategy -- considering time, nothing that it would take more than a few days of learning -- to create an algorithm for signature matching in R or Python?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is too broad and not suited for SO. You might try it on Data Science stack exchange.

Comment: But it is also a community with a higher number of users. The probability that someone 'knows' the answer it is higher. Questions like this one should have a tag rather than be placed in another stackexchange.